# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream error

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

It gives `operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream` error when I try to save the content of the file in the fileStream fs.

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
string[] fileList = appStorage.GetFileNames();

foreach (string fileName in fileList)
    {
       using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
       {
           if (fileName != "__ApplicationSettings")
           {
               var fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, appStorage);
               string abc = fs.ToString();
               meTextBlock.Text = abc;
               //MemoryStream ms = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

               clientUpload.UploadAsync(SkyDriveFolderId, fileName, fs);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you add the inner `using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))`?

Seems to me the problem is that you're opening a stream to read the file and then opening another, without closing the previous one!

If you remove that line (seems not to be doing anything there) it should work fine.

Oh, and the `fs.ToString()` will only get you the Type name, not the file content; to read the file, use a `StreamReader` with the `fs`.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot Pedro Lamas. The problem was with `using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))`

Comment: thanks! I had the exact problem and you solved it! I had to close the file stream before starting to work with another one

Answer (score 1):

This error consistently occurs when an isolated storage file is opened by one stream (or reader or else) and, is being accessed by another object while the first stream (or reader, or else) have not yet relinquished the file. Go through your code carefully in all places where you access isolated storage files and make sure you close each file before something else is accessing it. Pedro Lamas is correct for this particular case, I just wanted to provide some general feedback. If you search google for "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream error" questions and answers, you will see the trend. The error message could be more descriptive though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (IsolatedStorageFile.IsEnabled)
                    {
                        if (isf.FileExists(localFileName))
                        {
                            using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Open, isf))
                            {
                                using (var sr = new StreamReader(isfs))
                                {
                                    var data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                                    if (data != null)
                                    {
                                       ...
```