# IsolatedStorage permission error

Tags: windows-phone-8

I get a "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" error when i try to run this code:

```
  using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                if (!isf.FileExists("Lokacije.abc"))
                    isf.CreateFile("Lokacije.abc");

                using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Lokacije.abc", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.ReadWrite, isf))
                {
                    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        sw.Write(string.Format("GC-X({0})-Y({1})|", x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?
I am not using the storage in any other place in my application so its impossible that it is already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you don't somehow have two threads accessing `IsolatedStorage` at the same time (ie. in VS Debug.View.Threads and verify that at the time of the exception you don't have multiple paths through the same IsoStore code).

For more refer these:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a1bb0b15-6bc0-4c63-ac94-ec1e63242cf1/operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream?forum=wpdevelop

[Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200840/)

Hope it helps!